# FastAPI - Swagger, Is there a way to apply a global dropdown menu for organizing schemas?

Tags: swagger, fastapi, openapi

Working on Backend with Django, FastAPI, and Swagger.
I've been tasked with creating a dropdown list (similar to the one in the image) where I should be able to select schemas related to any of the databases I have in the system.
In this project, we have 2 databases, one handling everything related to the organization, and another for the products we offer. If I select the "organization" option in the dropdown list, only the schemas related to "organization" will appear.

A link to someone with my same issue: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/246#issuecomment-1244991368

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMyly.png)

The project is enormous, and it seems that understanding Swagger better is the solution. I've searched everywhere on how to accomplish this task, but I haven't found anything useful.